# Why can't openai in R make a table

Tags: r, openai-api

I'm trying to write a simple table using openai in R.
When I drop this prompt into chat.openai.com it creates a fine table.
When I run it in R it makes a mess.

```
library(openai)
prompt = "create a table with colleges in the rows and class sizes in the column:

Maryland 51
Gettysburg 33
UCLA 41
Baylor 30"

vector = create_completion(  
  model = "text-davinci-003",
  prompt = prompt,
  max_tokens = 20,
  temperature = 1,
  echo = FALSE
)

vector_2 = vector$choices[1]

vector_2$text
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what do you mean by saying "it makes a mess". What is a "mess"? What error do you get?

Comment: This worked for me. The text it shows has `\n` for newline and pipe `|` separators of the table...you may also have truncated results with `max_tokens` of only 20 (try increasing). To see the text rendered with newlines try `cat(vector_2$text)` in your example.